# How to simplify my C# Code

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm developing Windows Form Application using DevExpress. I need Simplfy my C# Code
Below is the code I use:

```
 if (srch_lookup_chequebookno.Text == "Auto")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ChequeBook No : "+chequebookno+ " Saved Successfully.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    dtgridview = iCubeERP.Accounts.FinanceTransactions.BOChequeBook.getchequedetails("GridValue", chequebookno, "", "", "");

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ChequeBook No : " + srch_lookup_chequebookno.Text + " Updated Successfully.",  MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    dtgridview = iCubeERP.Accounts.FinanceTransactions.BOChequeBook.getchequedetails("GridValue", srch_lookup_chequebookno.Text, "", "", "");

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error message, it seems that your *dateEdit_periodfrom*  variable is of the ***DateEdit*** type (not ***SearchLookupEdit***).  ***DateEdit*** doesn't provide the *DataSource* property.  Make sure you are using a correct variable to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 0):

you must always put the success message box after the process finishes to make sure no exception will be triggered after the success message is shown. And to make it more readable, I added another line of codes

```
if (srch_lookup_chequebookno.Text == "Auto")
{

    dtgridview = iCubeERP.Accounts.FinanceTransactions.BOChequeBook.getchequedetails("GridValue", chequebookno, "", "", "");
    string msg = string.Format("ChequeBook No: {0} Saved Successfully", chequebookno);
    MessageBox.Show(msg, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else
{

    dtgridview = iCubeERP.Accounts.FinanceTransactions.BOChequeBook.getchequedetails("GridValue", srch_lookup_chequebookno.Text, "", "", "");
    string msg = string.Format("ChequeBook No: {0} Updated Successfully", srch_lookup_chequebookno);
    MessageBox.Show(msg, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: I have used your code am getting error like Error 1.cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons' to 'string'  and 2. The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string, string, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Thanks NoobProgger I got the solution